# How do I use Tkinter with Aptana 3?

Tags: python, tkinter, aptana

I've been using IDLE with Tkinter but it keeps crashing on me so I am switching to Aptana Studio 3 (which I already use for web development) with PyDev.  I can't get Tkinter to import properly.  I've edited the paths in sys.path through the project properties menu to include the locations [shown on the IDLE website](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/#how-python-chooses-which-tk-release-to-use), but it still does not import the module.

Has anyone tried to use Tkinter with Aptana 3? Any other recommendations on where to go from here?

Comment: I've used the eclipse plugin version of aptana 3 and Tkinter imports perfectly. Just `import tkinter` or `from tkinter import *` (in python 3).

Comment: Depending on your OS (read Mac OSX), then using the IDLE shipped by Apple is a sure way to never touch it again. If that is your case, consider using IDLE that comes with CPython distributed by python.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line in http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html says:

"This manual assumes that you have already have Python and/or Jython and/or IronPython installed in your machine, as well as Eclipse, Aptana Studio 2 or Aptana Studio 3."

So it should work with Aptana 3 :-)

Are you sure you're using the correct from Tkinter import / from tkinter import according to your python version?

Also, have you checked that the libs are correctly loaded into Aptana? Theres something with the /lib/ and /Lib/ that can cause problems. (not sure if this is what you mean you've done with the sys.path?)

Comment: I have PyDev set up and working, it's just Tkinter that's not working. I already updated the project PYTHONPATH in the properties menu to include the folder where Tkinter is located (/Library/Framewoks/Tk.framework & /Tcl.framework) but it still says 'unresolved import' and doesn't work

Comment: Hey again,
I have just downloaded and installed Aptana Studio 3 on my windows machine. I have imported one of my python projects (which uses tkinter) and have no problem running it. Could you please document how you have set up your build?

Comment: I had a similar problem when i installed aptana on eclipse. It wouldnt import ttk. I tried every single solution listed on the web yet the only thing that worked was to add python 3.2 to my interpreters (having 2.7, 3.0 and 3.2 now).